# How to access a panel inside a tabpanel for jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a panel inside a tabpanel of tabcontainer. I want to hide it on page load and show it when i select 1 from a radiobutton list. I am beginner in jquery. Please Help

Comment: Show html code of your tabcontainer and tabpanels. Use plugin or custom control ?

Comment: i am using ajax tabcontainer and tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you construct your tab control.

If you have a static tab control (html version), you can add an ID attribute to the panel you want to hide.

At the page load hide it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#id_of_panel").hide();
});
```

When you click the radio button call the .show() method.

Please let me know if this was clear enough.

---

**Edit:**
In case of ajax loading try something like this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ 
    ajaxOptions: {
        success: function(){
            $("#id_of_panel").hide();
        } 
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wCzqt/1/

Comment: i have an ajax tabcontainer and tab panel inside it

Comment: See my modified answer for ajax loading tab

Comment: its thowing the following error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method. I have written this :<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#tpnlRaiseMRF").tabs
        ({ 
            ajaxOptions: 
            {
                complete: function()
                {
                    $("#pnlRbtnlInhouseType").hide();
                } 
           }
        });
    });

Comment: It should be success instead of complete. Check out the link provided in edited post!

Answer (score 0):

You must find html element of tab panel(use source code of html page). Get DOM object with jquery selector and hide it .
About selectors can read here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Your tab control is the elementary div containter. It must have **class** or **id** attribute.

For expample. In result html tab control will be something like this:

```
   <div class="tab-ctrl">
      <div class="tab-panel">
          // first panel
      </div>
      <div class="tab-panel">
          // second panel
      </div>
   </div>
```

In example, try hide first panel

```
  $(".tab-ctrl .tab-panel:first").hide();
```

or

```
  $(".tab-ctrl .tab-panel:first").css("display", "none");
```

Probably your control has api function, that's can do it. Try read plugin documentation